# Azure.Core.ResponseHeaders in unit testing

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, moq

I'm trying to implement the new Azure.Storage v12 SDK and running into an issue with unit testing. Methods that call the Azure REST API return a `Azure.Response<T>` which contains the method `GetRawResponse()` to return an `Azure.Response`.

The implementation relies on using the headers found in `Azure.Response.Headers`, which is a struct of the type [Azure.Core.ResponseHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.responseheaders?view=azure-dotnet). I can create an instance of it, but when iterating over it it throws a null reference exception.

```cs
using Azure.Core;

var headers = new ResponseHeaders();
var headers.GetEnumerator(); //throws null reference error
```

As far as I can tell the object has no other constructors and when obtaining its members with reflection I also see no properties or fields it could iterate over.

Is it possible to create an instance that's capable iterating over or mocking it using Moq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Apparently it uses a private field called `_response` which has a method to retrieve the Enumerable. Using reflection I set the private field to an instance of `MyResponse` which inherits from the abstract `Azure.Response` and overrides the method to return the `IEnumerable<HttpHeader>`.

```cs
object headers = new ResponseHeaders();
var field = headers.GetType().GetField("_response", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
field.SetValue(headers, new MyResponse());
var responseHeaders = (ResponseHeaders)headers;
```